# Error using validateHandleToPrint in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run this function but matlab says:
Error using validateHandleToPrint (line 26)
No Figure to print.
why its going wrong?

Error in validate (line 17)
pj = validateHandleToPrint(pj);

```
function [ X ] = ques1( a,b )
l1=length(diag(a));
l2=length(diag(b));


for i=1:l2

b(i,i)=a(i,i);

print b

end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

The `print` function prints a figure to a printer, or to an image.

You probably want `disp` to display your result at the command line.